# Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel multiple data in one slide with Laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Data: 
$posts= Post::all();

Bootstrap Carousel:

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">                       
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
   Item One                         
</div>
<div class="item"> 
    Item Two                        
</div>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I have tried up with but it is not working.

I would like to dynamic like:
[image]

Comment: Please add some more information about what exactly about this is not working. What are the errors you are getting? How does the current behavior differ from desired behavior? Consider taking a look at [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i have used laravel chunk in loop and its working well. :)